# convert record entries in form of single rows into different columns in jupyter notebook with headers?#Python#Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pivot, reshape

I have text file that is unstructured. I imported it into jupyter notebook and I am trying to create 10 columns out of the this row using pandas in jupyter notebook. For example :
0   product/productId: B000GKXY4S
1   product/title: Crazy Shape Scissor Set
2   product/price: unknown
3   review/userId: A1QA985ULVCQOB
4   review/profileName: Carleen M. Amadio "Lady Dr...
5   review/helpfulness: 2/2
6   review/score: 5.0
7   review/time: 1314057600
8   review/summary: Fun for adults too!
9   review/text: I really enjoy these scissors for...
10
11  product/productId: B000GKXY4S
12  product/title: Crazy Shape Scissor Set
13  product/price: unknown
14  review/userId: ALCX2ELNHLQA7
15  review/profileName: Barbara
16  review/helpfulness: 0/0
17  review/score: 5.0
18  review/time: 1328659200
19  review/summary: Making the cut!
20  review/text: Looked all over in art supply and...
21
22  product/productId: B000140KIW
23  product/title: Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose ...
24  product/price: unknown
25  review/userId: A2M2M4R1KG5WOL
26  review/profileName: L. Heminway
27  review/helpfulness: 1/1
28  review/score: 5.0
29  review/time: 1156636800
30  review/summary: Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose...
31  review/text: These are the BEST scissors I hav...
32

### Output: I would like the 10 columns with each of its respective values as rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `split` your dataframe on `:` then expand it to columns and use `groupby` to get the values per columns. Finally we construct a dataframe with `pd.DataFrame` by zipping the column names with the values:

```
m = df['COL'].str.split(':', expand=True)\
              .groupby(0)[1].apply(list).reset_index()

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(m[0], m[1])))
```

```
# print first 6 columns, cause rest doesnt fit on screen
print(df.iloc[:, :6])


  product/price product/productId                        product/title review/helpfulness              review/profileName review/score
0       unknown        B000GKXY4S              Crazy Shape Scissor Set                2/2   Carleen M. Amadio "Lady Dr...          5.0
1       unknown        B000GKXY4S              Crazy Shape Scissor Set                0/0                         Barbara          5.0
2       unknown        B000140KIW   Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose ...                1/1                     L. Heminway          5.0
```